# How ICMP works without transport layer

Tags: networking, icmp

I was told that ICMP doesn't involve transport protocols such as TCP, UDP.
So how ICMP get generated?So I want to confirm one thing to see if my understanding is correct:

let's say I want to send an ICMP request to a server. The ICMP message doesn't have transport header and transport payload(data), is it correct?

Comment: "_let's say I want to send an ICMP request to a server._" That's not what ICMP does. ICMP is an integral part of IP, and ICMP requests are to the network layer, not the application layer. The biggest use of ICMP is to send IP error messages to a host, not makes requests.

Comment: @RonMaupin, so every ICMP message has transport header and data?

Comment: No. ICMP is an integral part of IP, a network-layer protocol. Just read the RFC; it explains it.

Comment: @RonMaupin so when we use ping, is transport layer involved?

Comment: No. Didn't you read the RFC? It explains ICMP. It's not a big or complicated RFC, and it is the very definition of ICMP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ICMP is a little confusing if you consider it as a **separate** protocol layer than IP layer (just because ICMP packets are encapsulated in IP packets), but as mentioned in comments above it is an **integral part** of IP layer.

The job of transport layer like TCP or UDP is to send data from end-to-end. But ICMP is not concerned with data transfer, rather its job is to help routers figure out the shape of internet and what direction to send packets.

> I was told that ICMP doesn't involve transport protocols such as TCP, UDP. So how ICMP get generated?

Your assumption that all packets on wire strictly needs to have a transport layer is incorrect as well.

Comment: OK, I seems to understand ICMP better. Thank you. So just want to confirm that ICMP can have transport involved (traceroute uses UDP)  or not having transport involved('Ping')

Comment: Quick question. Is ICMP the same as UDP but without the possibility to add customs messages? (Just a set of predefined numbers for diagnosis). Thanks for clarification.